# Relation between NOT gate and negative numbers 2's complement

Tags: combinatory-logic

The steps to get a number in 2's complement are simple:

1. Flip the bits (Using NOT)
2. Add +1 (afaik this step is done to eliminate the duplicate 0)

Recently I've seen an ALU design that can operate negative numbers in 2's complement without the seconds step. For example, we want to perform the following operation $y-x$

The ALU is basic, has the following inputs:

- x
- y

Following control flags:

- ny (Not y)
- f (0 = AND; 1 = ADD)
- no (Negate output)

There are more, but for the sake of this example its enough.

So, to execute the following operation $y-x$ we pass the ALU with:

- a: 2
- b: 2
- ny: 1
- f: 1
- no: 1

NOTE: The ALU doesn't have special circuitry to ADD +1, so what the ALU does:

1. Negate y: NOT(y) -> -3
2. Add x + -y = 2 + -3 = -1
3. Negate the output again: 0

So, as seen it jus works just like magic, without adding +1 to anyplace.

I've found the following relation between NOT and 2's complement numbers:

$NOT(y) = -(y+1)$

Actually, doing the same steps using this relationship, I get the same result which is correct:

1. Negate y: NOT(y) -> -3
2. Add x + -y = 2 + -3 = -1
3. Negate result: NOT(x + NOT(y))
4. Expand equation: -(x -(y+1) + 1)
5. Simplify equation: y-x

So you get the correct operation, double negating, im confused how this is possible, and where can I read more about this relationship?

Comment: "this step is done to eliminate the duplicate 0": what duplicate 0 ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833773/why-we-need-to-add-1-while-doing-2s-complement/57014625#57014625

Comment: There is no duplicate 0 in 2's complement.

Comment: Well, according to that answer that I've sent you there is, in 1's complement you have 2 ways of representing 0. When you add 1, you remove that "duplicate" 0 converting the number to 2s complement. But this is not the question

Comment: There is no duplicate 0 in 2's complement.

Comment: Well, not in 2s complement, but in 1s complement, to go from 1s complement to 2s complement you need to add +1 for that reason, so in 2s complement you dont have a duplicate 0 because you added +1.

Comment: No, adding 1 to -0 or +0  would still make two 1s.

Comment: So, is the answer (in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833773/why-we-need-to-add-1-while-doing-2s-complement/57014625#57014625) I sent you wrong then? whats the reasoning of adding +1 to get a 2s complement?

Comment: How much is -0+1 ?

Comment: I know, it's 0, but where do you get that from? From the link I sent you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833773/why-we-need-to-add-1-while-doing-2s-complement/57014625#57014625)

 now you have 2 different ways of writing the same number, both 0000 and 1111 represent 0.

> If you add 1 to these inverses they become 0001 and 1000 and represent the >numbers from -1 to -8 therefore you avoid duplicates.

Yes, 2s complement doesn't have duplicate 0 values. But 1s complement do has according to this quote (0000 and 1111  are 0)

Comment: What ? -0+1 is zero ??

Comment: 1 sry (rushed the answer), but still same question

Answer (score 1):

The 1's complement of a number $n$ equals $2^w-1-n$, where $w$ is the word length. The two's complement is $2^w-n$.

So $x-y=-(y+(-x))=2^w-1-(y+2^w-1-x)=2^w-(y+2^w-x)$ and the subtraction can indeed be made using 1's complement or 2's complement logic.

Comment: We know that 1s complement is just NOT'ing a number, from what I understand:
$NOT(y) = -(y+1)$
How does this equation $-(y+1)$ relates to this one $2^w -1 -n$ they get different results, how?

Comment: Could you clarify how 1s complement is equal to 2^w−1−n? from what Ive read NOT(y)=−(y+1) (1st complement)

Comment: @redigaffi: this is a well know elementary property. Work out examples.